# Angular Prime NG timeline not showing up on screen

Tags: html, angular, typescript, primeng, timeline

I'm trying to use the timeline from PrimeNGs documentation and it is not showing up on screen right now. What am I doing wrong that it's not shwoing up on screen? Also all necessary imports were already checked.

HTML:

```
    <p-timeline [value]="events">
      <ng-template pTemplate="content" let-event>
          {{event.status}}
      </ng-template>
    </p-timeline>
```

TS:

```
this.events: any[] = [
{status: "Step 1 done", date: new Date(2022, 9, 17, 10, 30)},
{status: "Step 2 done", date: new Date(2022, 9, 17, 11, 0)},
{status: "Step 3 done", date: new Date(2022, 9, 17, 11, 30)},
]
```

Comment: any console errors? post your module

Comment: No, nothing. When I'm using div-containers instead of ng-templates and using *ngFor instead of let-event it displays the content of the array as expected, but obviously not as a timeline.

Comment: can you please recreate issue on online dev environment & share the link?

Comment: Seems to work fine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-timeline-demo-br3e1g?file=src/app/app.module.ts